# Calculate the vertical room after a view in Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I need to calculate the distance from the end of a view to the end of the available room in the screen (excluding the bottom navigation bar)

Until now I was using:

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect );
int screenHeight = getRootView().getHeight();
int available= screenHeight - rect .bottom;
```

It was ok, but now trying on a Nexus 9 the `getRootView().getHeight()` returns 2048, that is, the full screen size, including status and navigation bar.

How can I fix that?